# How to run content script of google chrome extension after all the dom is created

Tags: google-chrome, content-script

I have a google chrome extension which need to get a video URL from the dom

```
var videolink = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].attributes.getNamedItem('src').nodeValue;
```

I found video element is created by javascript after the page is loaded. So I try to run the content script above in phase "document_idle". But seems the video element isn't initalized even then.

Is there any way I can use to run content script later then the video element be initalized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest, most robust, way to handle elements created/loaded by javascript, is to poll for them:

```js
var waitForVideo = setInterval (checkForElement, 150);

function checkForElement () {
    var videoElem       = document.getElementsByTagName ('video');
    if (videoElem.length) {
        clearInterval (waitForVideo);
        var videolink   = videoElem[0].getAttribute ('src');
        // DO WHATEVER, WITH videolink HERE.
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could try the brand-new [DOM Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_Mutation_Observers), but these were just added to Firefox and Chrome, and are probably overkill in this instance.

Comment: Brock, your solution works perfect! The only thing I changed is the waitInterval, change from 150 to 1000 because I found that in some case, the video element is get but I can't get the attribute to src, maybe this is because the src attribute isn't filled yet after the vedio element is created.

Comment: Excellent. The other approach for that would be to not clear the interval unless `videolink` was found too.

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit the page in your extension, you should be able to add a `onLoad=yourFunction()` attribute to the element so that it will call your function once the element is ready.